# How to open the bottom sheet that contains the list of applications for opening URL or google map. So the user can select their preferred application?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, browser, url-launcher

I tried this one. But, it Directly opens on the Google Maps application. The bottom sheet for choosing the preferred application is not showing. How do I achieve it? So, the user can select their preferred application.

This is my code for now,

```
 try {
                    launchUrl(
                      Uri.parse("geo:${taskAddress.lat},${taskAddress.lng}"),
                      mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
                    );
                  } catch (e) {
                  } finally {
                    launchUrl(Uri.parse(
                        "google.navigation:q=${taskAddress.lat},${taskAddress.lng}&mode=d"));
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do that. It's user device preferred setting. If the user set it to "Always Open" or similar it will not ask again.

Comment: If the user didn't set it to always open or it's a new mobile, Will the bottom sheet appears?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. But it also required the device to have more than one application that able to process that url scheme.